# How to constrain LocatorPane Dynamic point to a LogLogPlot line?

Tags: plotting, dynamic, locator

LocatorPane constrains to Plot[curve]:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
  Plot[x^3, {x, 10^0, 10^2}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], 
  Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], First[pt]^3}]]}], Appearance -> None]
```

[image]

However, LocatorPane does not constrain to LogLogPlot[line]:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
  LogLogPlot[x^3, {x, 10^0, 10^2}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], 
  Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], First[pt]^3}]]}], Appearance -> None]
```

[image]

Anyone know how to constrain the Locator point, or better yet constrain the Locator itself to a LogLogPlot line. If possible would then like to add horizontal Slider below graph to control locator. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map graphic coordinates `pt` to log-plot coordinates via `Exp`, apply function, and map back via `Log`:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
 LogLogPlot[x^3, {x, 10^0, 10^2}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], 
    Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], Exp[First@pt]^3 // Log}]]}], 
 Appearance -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]